# Does windows clean up memory after my C program?

Tags: windows, memory-management

I have a short C program, but with no garbage collection, so I assume there are some memory leaks. Does Windows free the memory used by the program when it has finished executing?

Comment: WHY on earth would you assume memory leaks?  You allocate memory, you free that memory. You open a file handle.. you close it!  It really isn't hard.
Don't rely on the operating system to clean it up for you (even though it will).  "Sloppy" is the only word I can use to describe engineers that code this way.

Comment: Well, I'm not an engineer, so....:-)

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is another Stack Exchange site, more programmer-oriented, that may be better suited to this sort of question, since you're writing your own programs.

Comment: Even though I do not know you, it makes me happy that you are learning.  I was just trying to let you know it doesn't have to leak.  GOOD LUCK!! :)  As @Christopher_Hostage mentioned, StackOverflow is the place for you.

Comment: Thanks! I know about memory management as a concept and that it should be used to prevent leaks, but for my tiny (a few hundred lines) first program I just wanted to firstly just get it working, and memory use so far should be minimal. Still I got curious if I was using up a tiny bit of memory each time I run the program... I actually started asking the question at stack overflow, but one of the criteria was "your question...Includes a bit of source code" and mine didn't, so I respected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When a process exits the OS will free all the resources that process was using.

For short and quick programs this means memory management isnt real important.  For longer running or complex programs it is very important though so it good to get in the habit of doing it properly.

Comment: If a process gets hung, and a user gets annoyed and opens another, then the user can make many useless copies of the program hanging around in virtual memory.  Check if an existing process exists and deal with it gracefully (prompting the user if they want to end the old process is one way to do it).